# How to Understand Concentrations Measurement

Tags: acid-base

I was helping out in my beginner's chemistry class today, as I'm a "lab assistant" of sorts, and was reading on a bottle of HCl: 1M. I'm assuming that is the concentration of how much hydrocloric acid is in the bottle, in moles, but how would you determine the concentration of the solution (thanks Ove)? What is the actual percentage of HCl to water(and whatever else is in the bottle)?

Comment: What do mean by "how do you compute that"? How to prepare a 1 M (1 mol/L) solution? Or how to determine the concentration of an existing solution?

Comment: This is a quite basic chemistry question in my opinion you should read [wiki molarity page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration) than ask what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The unit M is an abbreviated form of mol/L: 1 M = 1 mol/L, i.e. there is 1 mol of HCl per liter of solution. The M is pronounced "molar". For example, a solution with concentration 1 mol/L is said to be a "1 molar" solution.

In order to calculate the fraction of HCl in a 1 M solution, some information is needed. The density of the solution varies with concentration, so I looked up [1 M HCl on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20M%20HCl) and found $\rho = 1.016~g/cm^3=1.016~kg/L$. Also, the molar mass of HCl is $M_{HCl}=36.46~g/mol$. Thus, 1 L of solution has a mass of 1.016 kg and 1 mol of HCl weighs $$m_{HCl}=1~mol\cdot36.46~g/mol=36.46~g$$ The mass of water in the solution must therefore be $$m_{H_2O}=1.016\cdot10^3-36.46=979.5~g$$

From this, the mass fraction of HCl in the solution can be calculated:
$$w_{HCl}=\frac{m_{HCl}}{m_{tot}}=\frac{m_{HCl}}{m_{HCl}+m_{H_2O}}$$
Similarily, the molar fraction can be determined:
$$x_{HCl}=\frac{n_{HCl}}{n_{tot}}=\frac{n_{HCl}}{n_{HCl}+n_{H_2O}}=\frac{n_{HCl}}{n_{HCl}+\frac{m_{H_2O}}{M_{H_2O}}}$$